# php array random

Tags: php, arrays

I have php array

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 917
        [contentId] => 72
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.1","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"2d4f8f52d49d1ab9930bc40157013a31.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:16:30","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:05:57
        [sortorder] => 1
        [sitename] => bb6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 918
        [contentId] => 63
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.2","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"37154a5322838f61fb60cc24c8b5fe04.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:09:06","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:06:16
        [sortorder] => 2
        [sitename] => bb6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 919
        [contentId] => 64
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.3","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"f90ba1195b1dd5a57308b46e1b248d49.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:09:06","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:06:36
        [sortorder] => 3
        [sitename] => bb6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [boxId] => 920
        [contentId] => 65
        [sectionType] => hp_spl_contestants
        [contentTypeId] => 83
        [categoryId] => 0
        [countryId] => 5
        [data] => {"title":"Contestant No.4","button_txt":"Latest From","image":"d439ab109de8202914ea7439c1f7650b.jpg","author":"Meenakshi Negi","url":"","date":"2012-10-04 18:09:06","badget":0,"badget_date":""}
        [insertDate] => 2012-10-05 21:06:55
        [sortorder] => 4
        [sitename] => bb6
    )
```

can we randomise this array for its value

Comment: The values arent random compared to the first array example. But they could be shuffled. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function.

```
shuffle($cdata);
```

Comment: i have tried this one but doesn't work

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BeFMbB, check the example, it works. Note you only have 3 elements, so it will remain same with high possibilities.

Comment: yes it working but can you help me simmilar thing with following array

Answer (score 0):

shuffle() and array_rand() will help

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php